# How do I referente all ImageView in android studio? (java)

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, visibility

I have 5 ImageViews, and i want to hide all.
My code:

```
findViewById(R.id.foto1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.foto2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.foto3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.foto4).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.foto5).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I want to hide all of them once time, like:

```
Imageview.all.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

There is some way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Parent layout and keep all the imageviews as child. Then make the parent layout invisible

Your XML:

```
<LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or CoordinatorLayout etc..

 id = llayout>

     <ImageView 1/>
     <ImageView 2/>
     <ImageView 3/>
     <ImageView 4/>

</LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or CoordinatorLayout etc..>
```

your java:

```
llayout.setvisibility(INVISIBLE)
```